# What's the part at the end of the shoelace called in English?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

[image]

> What are the (usually) plastic part of the shoelace called? The end part I mean? Mine's broken but I can't do a DIY fix without knowing the name.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a [Jeopardy](https://www.jeopardy.com/) question if I ever saw one.  And I happen to know the answer..

This little doohicky is called an *aglet*.

> [**Aglet**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/aglet) (n): *A metal or plastic tube fixed tightly round each end of a shoelace.*

And now you know.  Go, impress your friends.

Comment: Never heard of this, you sure it's correct?

Comment: @user66531  Click the link.  It goes to the Oxford English Dictionary.  To be fair, almost no one has ever heard of this either.  It's not a commonly used word -- which is why I say it's the kind of thing that would be asked in a TV quiz show.   Like how to spell "Albuquerque" without looking in a dictionary.

Comment: FYI, the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/) is an entirely different dictionary, and it's not freely available online.  Your link goes to the Oxford Dictionaries website, which has online versions of the Oxford Dictionary of English, as well as its American edition, the New Oxford American Dictionary.  Although their website is rather confusing so it's an easy mistake to make, [they *do* have a FAQ entry where they explain the difference](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/news-and-press/oxford-dictionaries-faq); search for "What’s the difference between the OED" [...]

Comment: I feel that I have seen this question appear a lot, and always with the comments, "Never heard of this", and, "almost no one knows this". ;-) :-)

Comment: @Mick I always figured the kind of people who answer questions on ELL are proud of their Jeopardy skills, and like to find ways to mention all the things they know that "most people" don't.  :)